# Basis for orthogonal complement from matrix with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}-i&5&4\\ -i&1&0\\ i&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ where each $v_i$ is a column vector of $A$. Find a basis for the orthogonal complement $V^{\perp}$ with the reqular inner product for $\mathbb{C}^{3\times1}$.

I found the basis with the following computations $$A^Tx = \begin{bmatrix}-i&-i&i\\ 5&1&0\\ 4&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \implies x_1 = -\frac{1}{4}x_3 \text{ and } x_2 = \frac{5}{4}x_3.$$

So the basis would be defined by $\begin{bmatrix}-\frac14\\ \frac54\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm just wondering that is the matrix vector product $A^Tx$ something I can do since I'm not considering the complex conjugate at all?

Comment: why are you using $A^T$?  for starters, transposition doesn't correspond with the regular inner product over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @user8675309 Since $V^{\perp} = \ker(A^T)$?

Comment: @DanielLi If you're using the regular inner product over $\Bbb C^{3 \times 1}$, then you should be using the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) $A^*$ instead of the transpose $A^T$. In other words, we have $\operatorname{im}(A)^\perp = \ker(A^*)$ instead of $\ker(A^T)$.

Comment: @DanielLi You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3485229/81360) to be helpful