# Matrix expression of the scalar product between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose

My question is in regarding the adjugate matrix in the expression my teacher gave me of the scalar product: $$ \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}=x^+ G y$$ being $x^+=\overline{x}^T$ the traspose of the conjugate, in the complex plane. I know that in the real plane, $x^+=x^T$ so the expression becomes $x^T Gy$ as everyone is familiar with. But the thing is that if this is true, why when finding the inverse of a matrix $A$ (let's assume now *all* the elements are real of this matrix) with cofactors the expression is: $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\text{det} A} (A^+)^T$$ and until now, in that expression the adjugate was used finding the cofactors as in with each element of it being $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j} \alpha_{ij}$ and then transposing it, *while* due to the logic before, since all terms are real it should just be $x^+=x^T$? . Have I been conflicting two different terms or how are both things the same?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a precise definition of $A^{+}$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician isn't there already a precise definition? I wrote "being $x^+$ the adjugate, or the transpose of the conjugate", also known as $\text{adj }A$ or $A^*$, but my teachers writes it like that

Comment: Okay I might have realised, it must be because the first one is a column vector and the second one, the inverse one, is for matrices, it must be so

Comment: If all that you mean by $A^{+}$ is the adjugate of $A$ that's nothing at all to do with $x^{+}=\bar{x}^T$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I know now, but both are called adjugate so that confused me, the thing is that one is for vectors and the other is for the matrices, isn't it?

Comment: @Aley20 You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3485229/81360) to be helpful

Comment: @Aley20 Typically (in my experience), the conjugate-transpose of $A$ is called the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $A$. In contrast, the "adjugate" usually refers to the [transpose of the cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). The conjugate-transpose of $A$ is typically denoted as $A^*$ if you're a mathematician and as $A^\dagger$ if you're a physicist, which is what I suspect you had in mind when you wrote $A^+$.

Comment: @Aley20 Confusingly, both $A^\dagger$ and $A^+$ are used to refer to the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)

Comment: @Aley20 Note that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ always refers to [the matrix that I call the adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and $A^*$ always refers to the conjugate-transpose, which is completely unrelated to $\operatorname{adj}(A)$. (Actually, that last statement is a bit of a lie: physicists often use $A^*$ to refer to the conjugate without any transpose, i.e. instead of $\bar A$).